# Earning a percentage of the transaction fees generated by a smart contract

Tags: nearprotocol

How is that possible after revoking access keys to a contract? is there a standard design pattern to enable that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any "standard design pattern" here. One way to do this is to have some method that only some permissioned account(s) can call to retrieve tokens from the smart contract. You can implement any logic you like in that method, including how much NEAR can be withdrawn each time.

More concretely, it looks like

```rust
pub fn claim_owner_rebate(amount: U128) -> Promise {
   assert_eq!(env::predecessor_id(), self.owner_id);
   // do some stuff to check whether this amount can be withdrawn
   // ...
   Promise::new(env::predecessor_id()).transfer(amount)
}
```